# Export Windows Mobile Contacts to VCard

Tags: windows-mobile, compact-framework

How to Export Windows Mobile Contacts to VCard using .NET (C#)? I need to export Contacts from Windows Mobile and restore it to Windows (Desktop) which uses VCard format.

Answer (score 0):

VCards are [a very simple format text document](http://www.w3.org/2002/12/cal/vcard-notes.html).  You then can use the [`Microsoft.WindowsMobile.PocketOutlook.Contact` class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.windowsmobile.pocketoutlook.contact_members.aspx) to extract the contact information and then use something like a TextWriter to create the VCard file.

Comment: Thanks. Everything is fine except for VCard picture. How to export Picture to VCard format?